# suggestion completion across multiple types in an index

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to do a suggestion completion on a type? I'm able to do it on an index.

```
POST /data/_suggest
{
  "data" : {
    "text" : "tr",
    "completion" : {
      "field" : "sattributes",
      "size":50
    }
  }
}
```

when I do on a type:

```
POST /data/suggestion/_suggest
{
  "data" : {
    "text" : "tr",
    "completion" : {
      "field" : "sattributes",
      "size":50
    }
  }
}
```

**`suggestion`** is the type.

I don't get any results. I need to do suggestion on two different types articles and books. Do I need to create separate indexes to make them work or is there a way in elasticsearch to accomplish this? In case if I have to search on my index `data` is there way to get 50 results for type `article` and 50 results for type `book`.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Lucene has no concept of types, so in Elasticsearch they are simply implemented as a hidden field called `_type`. When you search on a particular type, Elasticsearch adds a filter on that field.

The completion suggester doesn't use traditional search at all, which means that it can't apply a filter on the `_type` field.  So you have a couple of options:

1. Use a different completion suggester field per type, eg `suggestion_sattributes`, `othertype_sattributes`
2. Index your data with the `_type` as a prefix, eg `type1 actual words to suggest`, then when you ask for suggestions, prepend `type1` to the query
3. Use separate indices

In fact, option (2) above is being implemented at the moment as the new [ContextSuggester](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/4044) which will allow you to do this (and more) automatically.

Comment: the ContextSuggester looks cool, but for anyone who is looking for context mapping for term or phrase suggestions, I'm just adding this message as a warning that this functionality is only available for completion.